# Copying and pasting features using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, features, copy, paste

I have created a table join between two shapefiles which I've named 'OSMM' and 'Mastermap'. I want to copy and paste all features (polygons) without a match from the target layer ('Mastermap') into the parent shapefile ('OSMM'). I can't find any up-to-update code for QGIS 3.6.

Here is my code so far:

```py
#1. loads the SHP files
uri = 'C:/Users/xx/Downloads/OSMM.shp'
vlayer = iface.addVectorLayer(uri,"","ogr")
uri = 'C:/Users/xx/Downloads/Mastermap.shp'
vlayer = iface.addVectorLayer(uri,"","ogr")

#2. Joins "InvoiceNum" from OSMM to Mastermap
layerToJoin = QgsProject().instance().mapLayersByName('OSMM')[0]
target = QgsProject().instance().mapLayersByName('Mastermap')[0]
myJoin = QgsVectorLayerJoinInfo()
myJoin.setJoinFieldName('InvoiceNum')
myJoin.setTargetFieldName('InvoiceNum')
myJoin.setJoinLayerId(layerToJoin.id())
myJoin.setUsingMemoryCache(True)
myJoin.setJoinLayer(layerToJoin)
myJoin.setJoinFieldNamesSubset(['InvoiceNum'])
target.addJoin(myJoin)

#3. Selects NULL features from Mastermap
params = { 'EXPRESSION' : '\"OSMM_InvoiceNum\" is NULL', 'INPUT' : 'C:/Users/xx/Downloads/Mastermap.shp', 'METHOD' : 0 }
processing.run("qgis:selectbyexpression", params)
```

So how do I perform the PyQGIS version of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on 'Mastermap' and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> into 'OSMM'?

Presumably I will then need to use the following code:

```py
#5. Save the changes
OSMM.commitChanges()
```

Comment: Try the "Append Features to Layer" plugin (documentation [here](https://github.com/gacarrillor/AppendFeaturesToLayer#append-features-to-layer)) and let me know if that works for you using the algorithm's GUI (it has an option to only copy selected values). If that works, I can write a full answer on how to use it from PyQGIS below.

Comment: @GermánCarrillo - That's a neat plugin, thanks for sharing!

Comment: @GermánCarrillo - Yes, thanks for sharing. I have tried it out and it works perfectly!

Comment: Good, I'll elaborate an answer now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To copy & paste features from one layer to another layer you have several options. These are two that I recommend:

## OPTION A: Using iface object

1. Select features in `source_layer`.
2. Use `iface.copySelectionToClipboard(source_layer)`
3. Open the edit session in `target_layer`.
4. Use `iface.pasteFromClipboard(target_layer)`
5. Save changes to `target_layer`.

Note that 1, 3 and 5 could be done programmatically as well, which is well covered by the [PyQGIS Cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/).

## OPTION B: Using 'AppendFeaturesToLayer' plugin

The '[Append Features to Layer](https://github.com/gacarrillor/AppendFeaturesToLayer)' is a plugin based on the QGIS copy&paste's code.

The plugin works even if your source and target layers don't share all fields (just as QGIS copy&paste does!).

### How to call it from PyQGIS

After installing the plugin, use a normal processing call depending on your use case:

**1. Copy all features from source layer to target layer:**

```
params = {'SOURCE_LAYER': source_layer, 
          'TARGET_LAYER': target_layer,
          'ACTION_ON_DUPLICATE' : 0}  # 0: Just append all features

processing.run("etl_load:appendfeaturestolayer", params)
```

**2. Only copy selected features from source layer to target layer:**

```
params = {'SOURCE_LAYER': QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(source_layer_path,
                                                               True), 
          'TARGET_LAYER': target_layer,
          'ACTION_ON_DUPLICATE' : 0}  # 0: Just append all features

processing.run("etl_load:appendfeaturestolayer", params)
```

---

NOTE: If you're more interested in the details, you can actually read the Python code of the algorithm. The key part is to establish a mapping between source and target layers: [See the code](https://github.com/gacarrillor/AppendFeaturesToLayer/blob/master/AppendFeaturesToLayer/processing/algs/AppendFeaturesToLayer.py#L186).

This is the GUI of the algorithm:

[image]

Comment: There seems to be 2 open brackets here but 1 closed creating a syntax error

Comment: Solved with the following: { 'INPUT' : QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition('C:/Users/xx/Downloads/Mastermap.shp', True)

Comment: Right, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: From PyQGIS, is that possible to use a temporary layer as source layer? What would be the "source_layer_path" argument then?

Comment: I'd run any other processing algorithm using such layer as input, and afterwards, look at the Processing History to see how Processing expects the input for a temporary layer.

Answer (score 2):

**Finally, here is te code to make a "Copy-Paste".**

This PyQgis Script allow to Copy some selected features (in this case,; Farms (Predios)) from an Origin_Layer (Actas Trabajo), and Paste it into a Destination_Layer (Predios Lineas).

The variables was written in Spanish to make it easier to understand to my Spanish Colleges.

You must Change the names of Origen_Layer and Destination_Layer, for yours.

**Enjoy... JC**

```
#=========================================================================
# Copia los polígonos de un predio seleccionado desde la capa de "Actas"
# y los pega en la capa de "Predios por línea"
# Escrita por Juan Carlos Jerez
# Openfields.cl"
#=========================================================================

#From Layer...
CapaOrigen = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("Actas Trabajo")[0]

#Destination Layer...
CapaDestino = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("Predios Lineas")[0]

#Dialog Box for input "ID del Predio" to select it...
ID_Predio = QInputDialog.getText(None, 'ID del Predio', 'Input ID del Predio')
Predio = int(ID_Predio [0])   #String to Number

#select the polygons to copy from...
CapaOrigen.selectByExpression('"ID_Predio" = {}'.format(Predio), QgsVectorLayer.SetSelection)

#Store selected polygons in a list....
#to know the numbers of selected polygons...
Pol_seleccionados = CapaOrigen.selectedFeatures()
print("Número de polígonos seleccionados: ",len(Pol_seleccionados))

#Detect if there are selected polygons...
if len(Pol_seleccionados) == 0:
    print ("==================================================")
    print ("NO hay polígonos para el Predio ", Predio,"... Check.")
    print ("               FIN DEL PROCESO")
    print ("==================================================")
else:
    #===========================================================
    #Copy the selected polygons
    iface.actionCopyFeatures().trigger()
    
    #Change and Activate the Destine Layer 
    iface.setActiveLayer(CapaDestino)

    #Put the Destine Layer in Edition
    CapaDestino.startEditing()

    #Paste the selected polygons
    iface.actionPasteFeatures().trigger()

    #Zoom to selected...
    iface.mapCanvas().zoomToSelected()
        
    #Save
    CapaDestino.commitChanges()
    print ("==================================================")
    print ("Capa actualizada con el Predio ", Predio)
    print ("               PROCESO EXITOSO")
    print ("==================================================")
```